# Escape dot in GString

Tags: groovy

I have a string like this

```
def fileName = "$prefix-$currDate.gz"
```

.gz is an extension of the file and not a property and I get exception that there is no such property.

Is there a way to escape it? I tried \. which didn't work.

I know I could do

```
def fileName = "$prefix-$currDate" + ".gz"
```

but that's not too groovy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"$prefix-${currDate}.gz"
```

should be good.

Comment: That worked, just starting with groovy, so sometimes might ask stupid questions.

Comment: Not a problem. All that matters is you started with Groovy. :)